# How do I show a list of ~150 items when editing in a table?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-expectation

I'm working on finding a solution for the table that allows inline editing. One of the fields allows the user to select from a list of items (up to ~150 items to choose from).

I've thought of a few ways to solve this, but I'm unsure as to which is best for this situation.

Here is the original layout:

[image: Original wireframe]

Now the questions is **in this situation, should I show the list of options in**

- **a sidebar**
- **a popover**
- **a dropdown**

Below, I have sketched out each option.

### Sidebar

The sidebar seems to be the most versatile, and did well with some initial user testing, so I'm leaning towards this option.

[image: Sidebar option]

### Popover

[image: Popover option]

### Dropdown (afraid of scrolling in small screen to 150 items)

[image: Dropdown option]

Comment: Thanks @maxathousand. I found a solution as well as tested with couple of users I am going with sidebar component as its versatile.

Comment: Guys . Please take a look on the attached wireframe and share your suggestions.

Comment: I've rewritten your question, largely to include the wireframes in the question body (we're lazy, hahha). Please feel free to correct anything I might have gotten wrong.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @maxathousand, Perfect this is what I am looking for. yup we're lazy :) hahaha ... Really appreciate for your help on rewriting the question..

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that the list of data is about 150 words long, the best option would be to have a vertical sidebar.

Usability studies have shown that it is easier for humans to scan vertically arranged data faster than horizontal layout. It gives the eye an edge to follow like the left edge in case of left aligned data.

For example, check this out on this website itself:
[image: List of related questions shown in a right sidebar, arranged vertically]